Decrypting my Techem WM-bus heat meter didn't work, even while using my AES key
I have a Techem heat meter that speaks WM-bus and I also got an AES key from Techem. Do I need an IV to decrypt my telegram.
I tried using Laravel openssl_decrypt to decrypt.
// Decrypt the payload using AES ECB mode
$decryptedPayload = openssl_decrypt(
  $binaryEncryptedPayload,
  'aes-128-ecb',
  hex2bin($keyHex);
);

